# Swift 3 : nil when trying to get email from Twitter using Fabric

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8, twitter-fabric

I'm using this statement to get user email from Twitter :

```
I tested this code and it returns a nil for the email address!                                      `  let client = TWTRAPIClient.withCurrentUser()
                    let request = client.urlRequest(withMethod: "GET",
                                                    url: "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json",
                                                              parameters: ["include_email": "true", "skip_status": "true"],
                                                              error: nil)

                    client.sendTwitterRequest(request) { response, data, connectionError in
                        if (connectionError == nil) {

                            do{
                                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! [String:Any]
                                print("Json response: ", json)
                                let firstName = json["name"]
                                let lastName = json["screen_name"]
                                let email = json["email"]
                                print("First name: ",firstName!)
                                print("Last name: ",lastName!)
                                print("Email: ",email!)
                            } catch {

                            }

                        }
                        else {
                            print("Error: \(connectionError)")
                        }
                    }
```

`

But unfortunately it returns nil!

I already whitelisted my App and i got an email from Twitter team telling me that all authorisations are granted for my App.

[image: email from Twitter]

Comment: Twitter API stop to return emailID in its response.

Answer (score 1):

There is no configuration issue with your app and Twitter SDK. You are getting nil in return because the user has not permitted the access to `Email` field from his profile privacy settings. You can change the privacy settings and start getting this value in your code. OR user has not added email id in the account.

Comment: i get the email on my Android Application using the same Twitter account. And i tried the code in Fabric docs with no lack. [link](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/twitter/log-in-with-twitter.html#request-user-email-address)

Answer (score 0):

The API won't return an email address to you. If you're interested in a user's email address, you'll have to ask the user for it within your own application as a completely distinct act.

Comment: // Swift
let client = TWTRAPIClient.clientWithCurrentUser()
let request = client.URLRequestWithMethod("GET",
  URL: "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json",
  parameters: ["include_email": "true", "skip_status": "true"],
  error: nil)

client.sendTwitterRequest(req) { response, data, connectionError in }

Comment: See my updated post. I tested this code and i still get nil for the email address.